# "Message: Unable to locate element" when looking for the first image

Tags: python, selenium

again!

I'm trying to build a Pinterest webscraper and I want the program to log in Pinterest, search for "South Korea" and get the first image's attribute and print it out.
Here's the code:

```
    py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python Projects\Nova pasta\geckodriver.exe'))
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    
    browser.get("https://pinterest.com/") # Opens Firefox and enters Pinterest
    
    login = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.erh") # Looks for the login button
    login.click() # Clicks on it
    
    email = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#email") # Looks for the email box
    email.send_keys("") # Types in the email
    
    password = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#password")
    password.send_keys("")
    
    login2 = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".red > div:nth-child(1)")
    login2.click()
    
    search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='searchBoxInput']")))
    search.click()
    search.send_keys("South Korea")
    search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 60)
    
    image1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/img")
    src = browser.get_attribute("srcset")
    
    print(src)
```

However, I get this error message:

```
File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python Projects\Nova pasta\bruh.py", line 33, in <module>
    image1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/img")
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/img
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

What went wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a race condition where the found element is executing before it is present on the page. Take a look at the [wait timeout documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). Here is an example from the docs

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```